# How do I combine array values with array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}, {:foo => 2, :bar => 4} ...]
```

And an array of integers:

```
[3, 6]
```

I want combine the values from the integer array and the hashes to end up with something like:

```
[{:foo => 1, :bar => 2, :baz => 3}, {:foo => 2, :bar => 4, :baz => 6}]
```

I am currently doing this:

```
myArrayOfHashes.each_with_index |myHash, index|
    myHash[:baz] = myArrayOfIntegers[index]
end
```

Is that the right approach?

I was imagining a more functional approach where I iterate over both arrays simultaneously, like something using `zip` + `map`.

Comment: It's not necessary to repeatedly specify you want to do this with Ruby. The tags you set will tell us the language and features or libraries.

Comment: Yeah, good call @theTinMan.  Just never sure if favorite tags are used by the person who could answer.  But, noted for the future.

Comment: If someone tries to answer who *hasn't* paid attention to the tags, the odds are really good they'll get plenty of down-votes for not having paid attention. They won't repeat that.

Comment: Your current implementation looks good enough for me already

Comment: @JanDvorak +1 for efficiency and less memory consumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
require 'pp'

ary_of_hashes = [{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}, {:foo => 2, :bar => 4}]
[3, 6].zip(ary_of_hashes).each do |i, h|
  h[:baz] = i
end

pp ary_of_hashes
```

Which results in:

```
[{:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>4, :baz=>6}]
```

`zip` is a good tool for this, but `map` won't really buy much, at least nothing that you can't do as easily with `each` in this case.

Also, don't name variables using CamelCase like `myArrayOfHashes`, instead use snake_case, like `ary_of_hashes`. We use CamelCase for class names. *Technically* we can used mixed case for variables, but by convention we don't do that.

And, it's possible to use `each_with_index`, but it results in awkward code, because it forces you to use an index into `[3, 6]`. Let `zip` join the respective elements of both arrays and you'll have everything you need to massage the hash.

Comment: Try `ri Kernel.pp` from the command-line, or check http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Very good.  I figured I could use zip here and do exactly this, not sure what mistake I was making when I tried it earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I also follow those conventions when actually writing code.  I am not sure why I decided to write my sample like that - I guess too much scala recently.

Answer (score 6):

`map` is useful when you want to leave the original objects intact:

```
a = [{:foo => 1, :bar => 2}, {:foo => 2, :bar => 4}]
b = [3,6]
a.zip(b).map { |h, i| h.merge(baz: i) }
# => [{:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>4, :baz=>6}]
a.inspect
# => [{:foo=>1, :bar=>2}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>4}]
```

Comment: According to the code sample in the question, it should be `a.zip(b).each {|h, i| h.update(baz: i)}` rather than creating a new Hash and leaving `a` unchanged.

Comment: I may have been over-reaching with looking to use map since it looks like it might not be necessary.  + 1 still though.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_of_hashes.each { |hash| hash.update baz: array_of_integers.shift }
```

Comment: Good (+1) but it destroys `array_of_integers`.

Comment: Caution with `array_of_integers.shift`. It'll be destructive.

Comment: Right, to preserve the array of integers, `array_of_integers.dup` should be called first.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky how is mine? :)

Comment: @OMG: Mandadory +1 first, now lemme see ... you are running an index ... bad ... but using `with_index` ... good ... ... ... A valid possibility; I'd have used more whitespaces.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I got down-vote. But could you edit my answer as you suggested, I don't understand your advise :(..

Comment: @OMG: Your option is legitimate, but voting mistakes happen. But if you really want to contribute, don't you happen to know the answer to [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203731)? I thought it was just a simple JavaScript question, but it's already up for 2 days, and nothing.